# What is the logic underlying javascript string comparisons?

Tags: javascript

Apparently, the below javascript prints TRUE.

```
var s = "hippo";
var t = "Hippo";
var test = (s > t);
document.write(test ? "TRUE" : "FALSE");​
```

What makes "hippo" greater than "Hippo"? The ASCII value for H is greater than the ASCII value of h.

What is the logic underlying javascript string comparisons?

http://jsfiddle.net/dUadG/1/

Comment: The ASCII value of any lowercase letter is the ASCII value of the uppercase letter plus 32. `H` is 72, while `h` is 104!

Comment: "*The ASCII value for H is greater than the ASCII value of h.*" - check again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In *dictionary ordering*, we generally want lowercase to come after uppercase so that proper names show up first.  I suppose that doesn't have to be the case; that's just the convention for English speakers AFAIK.  "X Greater than Y" in strings means  "X shows up in a dictionary after Y".  So this is not unexpected.

Answer (score 2):

It's not ASCII, but UTF-16:

> ECMAScript source text is represented as a sequence of characters in the Unicode character encoding, version 3.0 or later. The text is expected to have been normalised to Unicode Normalised Form C (canonical composition), as described in Unicode Technical Report #15. Conforming ECMAScript implementations are not required to perform any normalisation of text, or behave as though they were performing normalisation of text, themselves. ECMAScript source text is assumed to be a sequence of 16-bit code units for the purposes of this specification. Such a source text may include sequences of 16-bit code units that are not valid UTF-16 character encodings. If an actual source text is encoded in a form other than 16-bit code units it must be processed as if it was first convert to UTF-16.

http://es5.github.com/#x6

Also try:

```
'h'.charCodeAt(0);
'H'.charCodeAt(0);
```

Comment: "*It's not ASCII, but UTF-16*" - why is that relevant? Both use the same codes for the same characters...

Comment: It's relevant because the OP thinks it's ASCII.

Comment: The question was about the general comparison algorithm, not only that particular case.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas Besides, in the face of Gabe's comment, you must admit that the numerical value of lowercase letters are not always 32 larger than the uppercase ones. Take Š for instance; its lowercase version is only 1 larger.